# How do I compute this metric projection?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I saw a result that says: Given a nonzero vector $a$ and the convex set $K:=\{y\in H: \langle a,y\rangle =\alpha, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ a hyperplane, then $$P_Kx=x-\frac{\langle a,x\rangle-\alpha}{\|a\|^2}a,$$  where $P_K$ denotes the metric projection.

Question: How did they compute this value?

Comment: For any vector $x,$ what is $\langle a,  P_K x \rangle?$ If $y$ is already a member of $K,$ what is $P_K y?$

Comment: The answer is $\alpha$. But I dont understand how it solves the question.

Comment: The other part is that if $y \in K,$ then $P_K y = y.$ This means that $P_K \circ P_k = P_K,$ which is one requirement for a projection. Another is that it be linear: $P_K(u+v) = P_K u + P_K v.$ As to how they computed it, they made an orthogonal projection onto a hyperplane $K$ that does not necessarily go through the origin.....what book is this in?

Comment: Oh: in this case, assuming $a \neq 0,$ orthogonal projection just means that $P_K x - x$ is a scalar multiple of $a.$ Note that the choice of the constant $\alpha$ does not change this property.